# How to add custom options programmatically for configurable product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, custom-options, custom

I tried to add custom option to a product into an observer on `catalog_product_save_after` event.

I am already successful add custom option for the simple product with this script:

```
class Productsaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{    
    protected $ObjectManager;
    protected $product;

    public function __construct(
         \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $ObjectManager,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
      ){

        $this->_objectManager = $ObjectManager;
        $this->_product = $product;

     }
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) 
    {

         $_product = $observer->getProduct();  
         $productId = $_product->getId();
         $personalisatie = $_product->getData('personalisatie_toevoegen');

         if(!$_product->getHasOptions() && $personalisatie==1 ){

        try{            
                $customOption = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface');
                $var = NULL;
                $customOption
                ->setOptionId($var)
                ->setProductId($productId)
                ->setType('field')
                ->setIsRequire("0")
                ->setSku("")
                ->setMaxCharacters("13") 
                ->setFileExtension("")
                ->setImageSizeX("0")
                ->setImageSizeY("0")
                ->setSortOrder("1")
                ->setDefaultTitle("Naam")
                ->setStoreTitle("Naam")
                ->setTitle("Naam")                
                ->setDefaultPrice("0.00")
                ->setDefaultPriceType("fixed") 
                ->setStorePrice("0.00")
                ->setStorePriceType("0.00")
                ->setPrice("10")
                ->setPriceType('fixed')                               
                ->setRecordId("0")                
                ->setProductSku($_product->getSku()); 

                $customOptions[] = $customOption;   

                $_product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                var_dump($e->getMessage());

            }


         }


    } 
}
```

But for the configurable product is not working at all.

What i see is that **!$_product->getHasOptions()** is not true. so the code is not executed for configurable product.

If I remove `!$_product->getHasOptions()` form **if** statement when i press save of the produc my backend page is loading for few minutes then and page is blocked and the custom options is not added.

Is there another way to add custom option for the configurable products?

Comment: Have you ge any solution. I have need to add product option custom value.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface::save` method to save custom options.

Replace

```
$_product->setOptions($customOptions)->save();
```

with

```
$this->optionRepository->save($customOption);
```

where optionRepository is `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface` instance

Comment: Could you please help me on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api