# Magento 2: Add product option custom value in product Rest API

Tags: custom-options, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I added custom field Image and Qty in Product `Customizable Options.` I add those filed to Product Option Value in Product Rest API. So how can it possible.

> Method: GET
>
> API Request URL:
>   http://localhost/magentosample231/rest/V1/products/24-MB01

**Reposne:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "sku": "24-MB01",
    "name": "Joust Duffle Bag",
    "attribute_set_id": 15,
    "price": 34,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "created_at": "2019-08-30 07:14:51",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-16 11:56:24",
    "extension_attributes": {
        "website_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "category_links": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "3"
            },
            {
                "position": 0,
                "category_id": "4"
            }
        ],
        "stock_item": {
            "item_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "stock_id": 1,
            "qty": 100,
            "is_in_stock": true,
            "is_qty_decimal": false,
            "show_default_notification_message": false,
            "use_config_min_qty": true,
            "min_qty": 0,
            "use_config_min_sale_qty": 1,
            "min_sale_qty": 1,
            "use_config_max_sale_qty": true,
            "max_sale_qty": 10000,
            "use_config_backorders": true,
            "backorders": 0,
            "use_config_notify_stock_qty": true,
            "notify_stock_qty": 1,
            "use_config_qty_increments": true,
            "qty_increments": 0,
            "use_config_enable_qty_inc": true,
            "enable_qty_increments": false,
            "use_config_manage_stock": true,
            "manage_stock": true,
            "low_stock_date": null,
            "is_decimal_divided": false,
            "stock_status_changed_auto": 0
        }
    },
    "product_links": [
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG086",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG083-blue",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-UG01",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "crosssell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WG085_Group",
            "linked_product_type": "grouped",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB02",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB05",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 3
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-MB06",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-UB02",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 5
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB03",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 6
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB04",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 7
        },
        {
            "sku": "24-MB01",
            "link_type": "upsell",
            "linked_product_sku": "24-WB07",
            "linked_product_type": "simple",
            "position": 8
        }
    ],
    "options": [
        {
            "product_sku": "24-MB01",
            "option_id": 1,
            "title": "Test",
            "type": "drop_down",
            "sort_order": 1,
            "is_require": true,
            "max_characters": 0,
            "image_size_x": 0,
            "image_size_y": 0,
            "values": [
                {
                    "title": "Test1",
                    "sort_order": 1,
                    "price": 10,
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "option_type_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "title": "Test2",
                    "sort_order": 2,
                    "price": 12,
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "option_type_id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "media_gallery_entries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "media_type": "image",
            "label": "Image",
            "position": 1,
            "disabled": false,
            "types": [
                "image",
                "small_image",
                "thumbnail"
            ],
            "file": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "tier_prices": [],
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "activity",
            "value": []
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "style_bags",
            "value": []
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "material",
            "value": []
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "color",
            "value": [
                {
                    "Title": "Color",
                    "label": "Black",
                    "code": "49",
                    "Visible on Storefront": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "strap_bags",
            "value": []
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "features_bags",
            "value": []
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "image",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "small_image",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
            "value": "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "options_container",
            "value": "container1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "msrp_display_actual_price_type",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "url_key",
            "value": "joust-duffle-bag"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "gift_message_available",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "required_options",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "has_options",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "image_label",
            "value": "Image"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "small_image_label",
            "value": "Image"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "thumbnail_label",
            "value": "Image"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "tax_class_id",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": [
                "3",
                "4"
            ]
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "<p>The sporty Joust Duffle Bag can't be beat - not in the gym, not on the luggage carousel, not anywhere. Big enough to haul a basketball or soccer ball and some sneakers with plenty of room to spare, it's ideal for athletes with places to go.<p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Dual top handles.</li>\r\n<li>Adjustable shoulder strap.</li>\r\n<li>Full-length zipper.</li>\r\n<li>L 29\" x W 13\" x H 11\".</li>\r\n</ul>"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "eco_collection",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "performance_fabric",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "erin_recommends",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "new",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "sale",
            "value": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

**See the reposne there is a "options"**

```
"options": [
        {
            "product_sku": "24-MB01",
            "option_id": 1,
            "title": "Test",
            "type": "drop_down",
            "sort_order": 1,
            "is_require": true,
            "max_characters": 0,
            "image_size_x": 0,
            "image_size_y": 0,
            "values": [
                {
                    "title": "Test1",
                    "sort_order": 1,
                    "price": 10,
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "option_type_id": 1
                },
                {
                    "title": "Test2",
                    "sort_order": 2,
                    "price": 12,
                    "price_type": "fixed",
                    "sku": "24-MB01",
                    "option_type_id": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

**I have to add my custom added options field** `Image` **and** `Qty` **in to the**  `Options` `Value` **like same as  below.**

```
 "options": [
    {
        "product_sku": "24-MB01",
        "option_id": 1,
        "title": "Test",
        "type": "drop_down",
        "sort_order": 1,
        "is_require": true,
        "max_characters": 0,
        "image_size_x": 0,
        "image_size_y": 0,
        "values": [
            {
                "title": "Test1",
                "sort_order": 1,
                "price": 10,
                "price_type": "fixed",
                "sku": "24-MB01",
                "option_type_id": 1,
                "image": "test.jpg",
                "qty": 2
            },
            {
                "title": "Test2",
                "sort_order": 2,
                "price": 12,
                "price_type": "fixed",
                "sku": "24-MB01",
                "option_type_id": 2,
                "image": "info.jpg",
                "qty": 1
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have added product custom option value to product Rest API using Plugin `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\ReadHandler` class.

Follow below file path to create custom module and add the product custom option value to the Product Rest API.

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/ProductoptionsApi/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_ProductoptionsApi',
    __DIR__
);
```

> File path: magento/app/code/Vendor/ProductoptionsApi/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_ProductoptionsApi" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/ProductoptionsApi/etc/webapi_rest/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\ReadHandler">
        <plugin name="updateProductCustomOptionsValue" type="Vendor\ProductoptionsApi\Plugin\ProductCustomOptionsValue"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/ProductoptionsApi/Plugin/ProductCustomOptionsValue.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ProductoptionsApi\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\OptionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;

class ProductCustomOptionsValue
{
    /**
     * @var ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $optionRepository;

    /**
     * @param ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface $optionRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductCustomOptionRepositoryInterface $optionRepository,
        \Vendor\ProductoptionsApi\Helper\OptionsProvider $optionProvider,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options $productOptions
    ) {
        $this->optionRepository = $optionRepository;
        $this->optionProvider = $optionProvider;
        $this->productOptions = $productOptions;
    }

    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\ReadHandler $subject, $result, $entity, $arguments = [])
    {
        $options = $dataOption = [];
        $productSku = $entity->getSku();
        $options = $this->productOptions->decorateArray($this->optionRepository->getProductOptions($entity));
        $dataOption = $this->optionProvider->getExtendedOptionsConfig($options, $productSku);

        if($dataOption != '' && $dataOption != null && $dataOption != '[]'){
            $entity->setOptions($dataOption);
        }else{
           $options = [];
            /** @var $entity \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface */
            foreach ($this->optionRepository->getProductOptions($entity) as $option) {
                $option->setProduct($entity);
                $options[] = $option;
            }
            $entity->setOptions($options);
        }
        return $entity;
    }
}
```

> File path:
>   magento/app/code/Vendor/ProductoptionsApi/Helper/OptionsProvider.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\ProductoptionsApi\Helper;

use \MageWorx\OptionBase\Model\Product\Option\Attributes as OptionAttributes;
use \MageWorx\OptionBase\Model\Product\Option\Value\Attributes as OptionValueAttributes;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image as ImageHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use MageWorx\OptionFeatures\Model\Image;
use MageWorx\OptionFeatures\Model\Product\Option\Value\Media\Config;

/**
 * class OptionsProvider
 */
class OptionsProvider
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $productOptions;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param array $components
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options $productOptions,
        OptionAttributes $optionAttributes,
        OptionValueAttributes $optionValueAttributes,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        Data $priceHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        Config $mediaConfig,
        ImageHelper $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {
        $this->productOptions = $productOptions;
        $this->optionAttributes = $optionAttributes;
        $this->optionValueAttributes = $optionValueAttributes;
        $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->priceHelper = $priceHelper;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->mediaConfig = $mediaConfig;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    public function getExtendedOptionsConfig($options, $productSku = '')
    {
        $config = $result = [];
        $optionAttributes = $this->optionAttributes->getData();
        $optionValueAttributes = $this->optionValueAttributes->getData();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $option */
        if (empty($options)) {
            return $this->_jsonEncoder->encode($config);
        }

        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $config[$option->getId()]['title']= $option->getTitle();
            $config[$option->getId()]['type']= $option->getType();
            $config[$option->getId()]['sort_order']= $option->getSortOrder();
            $config[$option->getId()]['option_id']= $option->getId();
            $config[$option->getId()]['product_sku']= $productSku;
            $config[$option->getId()]['is_require']= $option->getIsRequire();
            $config[$option->getId()]['max_characters']= $option->getMaxCharacters();
            $config[$option->getId()]['image_size_x']= $option->getImageSizeX();
            $config[$option->getId()]['image_size_y']= $option->getImageSizeY();
            foreach ($optionAttributes as $optionAttribute) {
                $preparedData = $optionAttribute->prepareDataForFrontend($option);
                if (empty($preparedData) || !is_array($preparedData)) {
                    continue;
                }
                foreach ($preparedData as $preparedDataKey => $preparedDataValue) {
                    $config[$option->getId()][$preparedDataKey] = $preparedDataValue;
                }
            }

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value $value */
            if (empty($option->getValues())) {
                continue;
            }
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($option->getValues() as $value) {

                foreach ($optionValueAttributes as $optionValueAttribute) {
                    $preparedData = $optionValueAttribute->prepareDataForFrontend($value);
                    if (empty($preparedData) || !is_array($preparedData)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['sort_order'] = $value->getSortOrder();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['price_type'] = $value->getPriceType();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['title'] = $value->getTitle();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['price'] = $value->getDefaultPrice();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['dependency'] = $value->getDependency();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['dependency_type'] = $value->getDependencyType();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['image'] = $value->getImagesData();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['option_type_id'] =  $value->getId();
                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['price_type'] =  $value->getPriceType();

                $config[$option->getId()]['values'][$i]['color_code'] = $value->getTitle();
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return $config;
    }

    public function getDependency($dependency){

        $dependencyArray=[];
        $dependency = json_decode($dependency);
        foreach($dependency as $key=>$value)
        {
            $dependencyArray['key'][$key]=$value[0];
            $dependencyArray['value'][$key]=$value[1];

         }
        return $dependencyArray;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look and I think you have to work around this class `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option`, there is a method called `addValue()` which is a public function. You might do a plugin.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, your given path is correct. I have also check to print the `$value` object in `addValue()` function and getting all the options. But how can I add that missing options to Product Rest API Options as a Value ?